# Is there a way to save the code folding in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, code-folding

When editing a large file, I like to collapse code fragments using the `+` symbols in Notepad++'s sidebar. However, the code is completely unfolded when I close and reopen a file.

Is there a way to store the state of folding in a file?

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer (saves and restores the entire set of tabs, not just the current file): File > Save Session...

Comment: This was the answer I needed, to help notepad++ remember my previous state of pages that had folded regions.  thanks!