# Notepad++: Save code folding status or open collapsed

Tags: notepad++, code-folding

I have found similar questions as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157518/how-to-save-collapse-status-in-notepad and [Is there a way to save the code folding in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/365246/is-there-a-way-to-save-the-code-folding-in-notepad). And http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/236/ says something like it has been implemented.

But I'm using Notepad++ 6.5 with Session Manager plugin (http://mfoster.com/npp/) and it doesn't work.

Regardless the size of the file, when I open it I usually Alt+0 to collapse everything so I can quicker find the method I want, and then go expanding as needed.

What I wanted then was that any possible collapse to be done (automatically execute Alt+0) when a file is opened. But it would be useful too if I'd close a file and when open it again it would remember collapse status.

Is anybody able to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The last link you gave is correct. Notepad++ saves the session when you close it and restores the session when you open it. That is what was implemented. Saving sub-sessions for individual files doesn't seem to be yet implemented anywhere.