# Fold Notepad++ region by default

Tags: notepad++

I recently found that notepad++ supports region folding similar to what Visual Studio does with .NET. I can put PHP inside of the region and then i can collapse it so the code isn't cluttering the screen.

```
#region Some code
...
#endregion
```

It's handy, but it doesn't remember what regions i closed last time. This is understandable as I am editing files over FTP. Is there anything that can be added to the region block that will let notepad++ know that this region should be collapsed by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to save the code folding in Notepad++?](http://superuser.com/questions/365246/is-there-a-way-to-save-the-code-folding-in-notepad)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate. I want to signal the fold using a comment or something as part of the region. Since it's FTP any cache or whatever won't store the fold state